# Time picker ONLY in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, timepicker

I am creating an vb.net page.  The page is to allow users to schedule lectures, appointments etc.   I have a few text boxes to add the details.  I have used the asp:calendar control to select the days.  However I cannot find a time picker.  To be clear I have three textboxes.  One for day, one for start time and one for end time.  All I want is a time picker.  When a user clicks a button or link a list pops up with times of the day.   The user clicks whichever time and I can get that time and store it in a variable to pass to my database, just like the calendar control.  Is that too much to ask.  Has anyone got an answer here.
I know this has been asked a multitude of times and I know there are answers out there but I have spent 9 hours so far playing around with the solutions out there, with no success, so I hoping please please please that someone here can help me.  I'm desperate and fed up, and it's probably my incompetence.

Comment: Have you found your solution ? may be you can accept the answer if any of them helped you..

Comment: You should probably consider moving away from ASP.NET forms and start learning MVC. It's just that the market is heading that direction and you are going to limit yourself if you don't follow.

Comment: I love giving unsolicited advice ;)

Comment: @harsh baid Yes I actually found another control that worked for me.  I have posted my answer but SO does not allow me to accept it yet.  Thank you for your reply though and your efforts to help me.  It is a always appreciated, especially for a novice like me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions guys.  I actually found a really good one myself at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213311/Time-Picker-Ajax-Extender-Control

It was very easy to use.  Just drag in the two folders "Binaries" and "Ajaxified" into your project.  Then, in the toolbox, right click and choose new item.  Navigate to the biaries folder in your solution and select the ajaxified.dll.   This will add the timepicker to your toolkit.  You can drag it onto your page. As it is an extender it has to be added to a target.  This will normally be a textbox.  It can be defined by the `TargetControlID="xxxxx` control.

I know this may be an overly specific guide but these things are only easy when you know how.    And 10 horrible hours late I can say I know how now.

NB It is a good idea to put the timepicker in a table cell with your target control, for formatting reasons.  Mine are also enclosed in DIV's

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [jQuery Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#tp-examples) it has many cool features such as

1. Timezones support
2. DateTime picker
3. Time picker
4. Jquery UI theming support and many other tweaks.

Usage is very simple and effective

**Example with date and time picker**

**HTML**

```html
<input type="text" name="basic_example" id="basic_example" class="hasDatepicker">
```

**Javascript**

```js
$('#basic_example').datetimepicker();
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

there is the simplest way 
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

```
<asp:Textbox Id="Date1" runat="server" />
<ajaxToolkit:Calendar runat="server"
    TargetControlID="Date1"
    CssClass="ClassName"
    Format="MMMM d, yyyy"
    PopupButtonID="Image1" />
```

and time picker like this
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: @Gavin wants `Timepicker` he already has calendar control.. !!